# Scala type checker cannot infer types correctly

Tags: scala, types

I simplified a problem that I had with Scala type inference:

```
  case class HalfEdg[N,E](e:E, n:N)
  case class Nod[N,E](head:N, edgs:HalfEdg[N,E])

  case class AA[E](e:E) {
    def ->[N](n:N):HalfEdg[N,E] = HalfEdg(e,n)
  }
  def --[E](e:E):AA[E] = AA(e)
```

And I can make this variable:

```
val x = Nod[Int,String](13, --("aa")->(12))
```

And then I want to extend it to following types:

```
  case class Foo[N](e:N => Boolean)
  case class Bar[E](e:E => Boolean)

  case class BB[E](e:Bar[E]) {
    def ->[N](n:Foo[N]):HalfEdg[Foo[N],Bar[E]] = HalfEdg(e,n)
  }  
  def --?[E](e:E => Boolean):BB[E] = BB(Bar(e))
```

But this time I cannot do the same thing because compiler cannot infer the type of function inside Foo and Bar: (I can statically type them and will compile)

```
  val x1 = Nod[Foo[Int],Bar[String]](Foo(x => x == 10), --?(x => x == "")->(Foo(z => z == 10)))
```

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

The type-inference failure is centered around the fact that the compiler can't figure out that the type `N` in `Foo(z => z == 10)` is the *same* `N` as the type `N` from the earlier `Foo(x => x == 10)`. One possible route around this is to ensure that the definitions of `Foo`, `Bar`, `BB`, and `--?` are all using the same `N` and `E`. This might be done by wrapping them in a parent ("context") trait parameterised with the types `N` and `E`. Eg:

```
trait Baz[N,E] {
  case class Foo(e:N => Boolean)
  case class Bar(e:E => Boolean)

  case class BB(e:Bar) {
    def ->(n:Foo):HalfEdg[Foo,Bar] = HalfEdg(e,n)
  }
  def --?(e:E => Boolean):BB = BB(Bar(e))
}
```

From here, you could perform the operations you need within a specific context, being a version of `Baz` with the particular desired types for `N` and `E` satisfied:

```
object IntStrBaz extends Baz[Int,String] {
  // do your work in here
  val x1 = Nod[Foo,Bar](Foo(x => x == 10), --?(x => x == "")->(Foo(z => z == 10)))
}
```

Pasting into the REPL, we no longer get type inference complaints:

```
scala> IntStrBaz.x1
res0: Nod[IntStrBaz.Foo,IntStrBaz.Bar] = Nod(Foo(<function1>),HalfEdg(Bar(<funct
ion1>),Foo(<function1>)))
```

Answer (score -1):

All you need is to simplify your expression and it will easily shows your errors.
You've missed two places to set type:

```
  val bbE = --?[String](x => x == "")
  val foo = Foo(z => z == 10)
  val zz = bbE->(foo)
  val x1 = Nod[Foo[Int],Bar[String]](Foo(x => x == 10), zz)
```

For such kind of problems it's much easier to identify the problem if you help compiler with type inference.

Comment: that't the whole question that why it cannot infer types! in the second case when it can do it in the first example! I know that if statically type everything it will work!

Comment: You can remove now. Ther problem was in invocation of functions `--?` and  `Foo`. You did not properly set `type` for them.

Comment: take a look onto your `--?` function. it's accept `x` - no information about type. what type scala can infer from it?

Comment: Sorry, but I cannot understand, would you please rewrite the structure provided in question in a way that it works or not?
if Yes, please do. if No, why it can do it in `Nod[Int,String](13, --("aa")->(12))`

Comment: try it `val x1 = Nod[Foo[Int],Bar[String]](Foo(x => x == 10), --?[String](x => x == "")->(Foo(z => z == 10)))`

Comment: yes, I know that with statically type that I will be able to solve it but my question is "How can I solve this problem?" without typing all the type!

Comment: Using without explicit types definition methods that are typized is absolutely incorrect. Especially when this type is _included into return value_ You are loosing information - that's where your problems come from.